# Pester Assert-MockCalled counts wrongly

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, pester

writing some tests with Pester and Powershell

Code:

```
Import-Module Module
Import-Module Pester

InModuleScope Module{

    Describe 'Add-Patchgroup' {

    Context 'Add_server_to_group_fail' {
        Mock Add-ADGroupMember {throw [ADIdentityNotFoundException]} 
        It 'NotCorrectNamingConvention' {
            {Add-Patchgroup -ComputerName "NotExistingServer" | Should -BeLike "WARNING: Could not reach*"}
        }

        It 'CorrectNamingConventionNotExistingServer' {
            {Add-Patchgroup -ComputerName "<nameOfTheServer>" | Should -Throw}
        }

        Assert-MockCalled Add-ADGroupMember -Exactly 1

    }
}
}
```

and got this output:

```
 Context Add_server_to_group_fail
      [+] NotCorrectNamingConvention 41ms
      [+] CorrectNamingConventionNotExistingServer 5ms
      [-] Error occurred in Context block 56ms
        Expected Add-ADGroupMember in module PsLeanOps to be called 1 times exactly but was called 0 times
        25:             Assert-MockCalled Add-ADGroupMember -Exactly 1
        at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\a.antr01\Desktop\AddPatchGroups.Tests.ps1: line 25
        at DescribeImpl, C:\Users\a.antr01\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\Functions\Describe.ps1: line 171
```

Why the mocked `Add-ADGroupMember` **wasn't** called? 
To clarify:

`Module` - module name

`Add-Patchgroup` - function in `PSLeanOps`

`Add-ADGroupMember` - AD cmdlet used in `Add-Patchgroup`

**EDIT**

Modified the code as TheIncorrigible1 said. Here is the final code:

```
Mock Add-ADGroupMember {throw [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException]::new()} 

            It 'CorrectNamingConventionNotExistingServer' {
                {Add-Patchgroup -ComputerName "<nameOfTheServer>" -ErrorAction Stop} | Should -Throw -ExceptionType "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException"
            }

            Assert-MockCalled Add-ADGroupMember -Exactly 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your assertions.  They shouldn't be in scriptblocks unless you're using `-Throw` (you are), but even then, only the command:

```
It 'NotCorrectNamingConvention' {
    Add-Patchgroup -ComputerName "NotExistingServer" | Should -BeLike "WARNING: Could not reach*"
}

It 'CorrectNamingConventionNotExistingServer' {
    { Add-Patchgroup -ComputerName "ATVT1WWFYC050" } | Should -Throw
}
```

---

As an aside, do you have a `using namespace` statement or adding to type accelerators in your code?  `[ADIdentityNotFoundException]` should throw a type not found exception (and presumably, be called twice since you're calling the function twice).

Comment: thanks for hinting me this small nuance. I've edited the question with the result.